# How can i use an aggregationStrategy and Dynamic Uris?

Tags: java, apache-camel

i want use an enricher with Dynamic Uris. I use Camel 2.17.5. Since 2.16 it is possible to use it. But how can i use an Aggregation Strategy and Dynamic Uris?

Documantation says:

```
.enrich().simple("http:myserver/${header.orderId}/order")
```

But this doesn't work:

```
.enrich(new StrategyEnrich()).simple("http:myserver/${header.orderId}/order")
```

This also not:

```
.enrich(simple("http:myserver/${header.orderId}/order"),new StrategyEnrich())
```

Knows any one the right syntax?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution:

```
.enrich()
    .simple("http:myserver/${header.orderId}/order")
    .aggregationStrategy(new StrategyEnrich())
```